# How to reuse objects in JUnit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I don't want to create the same objects for every unit test but I can't figure out how to reuse objects for multiple testing methods.

I know about `@BeforeAll` and I am trying to use it to initialize a set of static objects that I can reuse in multiple unit tests.

Somehow I can't get it to work.

For example, I could have a class called `Date` with the initializer `Date(int day, int month, int year)` and I am trying to test its `equals(Date other)` method. I now want to create `Date` objects that I can also use for other test methods.
This is what I am trying:

```
public class MyTests {
   
    static Date d1, d2, d3;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() {
        d1 = new Date(7, 11, 2021);
        d2 = new Date(7, 11, 2021);
        d3 = new Date(1, 11, 1990);
    }

    @Test
    public void TestDateEquals() {
        Assert.assertTrue(d1.equals(d2));
        Assert.assertFalse(d2.equals(d3));
    }
}
```

This throws a `NullPointerException`. How can I make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you initialize the `static Date`s right there? `final static Date d1 = new Date(7, 11, 2021); final static Date d2 = new Date(7, 11, 2021); final static Date d3 = new date(1, 11, 1990);`

Answer (score 1):

what junit version are you using ?
BeforeAll works for junit5(org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll) and assert is org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue

i ran you code with junit5 and it worked after add static to setup method. You also can follow @Turing85 suggestion to initialize the objects

Answer (score 0):

Any methods annotated by `@Before...` or `@After...` should be `static` to work properly.
Just mark your `setup()` method static and run.
That's a requirement of JUnit current implementation.